# Server 2012 R2, disk quota vs user quota

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, quota

I'm learning Windows Server configuration and I'm confused a little, because there are two (at least) apparently independent quota systems.

First one should be enabled per drive in drive properties, and then limits can be set for a user or a group. I think files are tracked by Ownership status and can be in multiple directories.

Second one is available in Resource Manager; it is working independently from the per volume quota. If user quota system is disabled for a drive I am still able to define a working quota for a specific folder.

Are this systems independent by design? Or am I missing someting?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server supports two mutually exclusive methods for setting quotas on the amount of file system resources a user can use—disk quotas or directory quotas. Disk quotas were introduced in Windows 2000, and are applied to specific users and limit the amount of disk space that user can use on a particular volume. Directory quotas are applied to all users and limit the amount of disk space that users can use in a particular folder and its sub-folders.

This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163561.aspx has very good explanation and although this link is for a older server but the general concept didn't change. Hope this helps